# Screen dimensions changed on iOS13 with Cordova after using certain plugins

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios13

I'm running a Cordova app and having an issue with iOS 13 on certain iPhones.  I've been using these plugins for years without an issue, until iOS 13.

When I run these plugins (cordova-plugin-email-composer, cordova-sms-plugin) on an iPhone with a notch (e.g., iPhone X or iPhone 11), after invoking the plugin and sending an email or cancelling out of sending an SMS message, I return to my app and the screen is "magnified."  That is, the content is pushed up, down, left, and right. When I run this on an iPhone 5s, it's all fine.

I don't know if this helps but I noticed that the screen dimensions have changed. When I ask jQuery before invoking the plugin my iPhone X dimensions:

$(window).height() = 768
$(window).width() = 375

after sending an email and returning to my app:

$(window).height() = 840
$(window).width() = 410

This only occurs on iOS13, iOS 12 is fine.

Tested on the latest versions of Cordova - 9.0.0 Cordova and cordova-ios 5.0.1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Jon

Comment: By ay chance, what version of xcode are you using right now?

Comment: I've been using 11.1 on one machine and 11.2 on another.  I just upgraded my 11.2 to 11.2.1.  But I'm finding a temporary workaround here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/issues/156 by doing StatusBar.hide() then StatusBar.show() in the callback of the plugins.  I'm having to do a little more work but so far my tests are positive!